# Django, phpBB and MediaWiki unified login

Tags: django, authentication, mediawiki, phpbb

I have a website built with Django that I would like to combine with phpBB (negotiable; if you have suggestions for better suited full-featured forums, please let me hear them) and MediaWiki. Specifically, I would like to have a unified login scheme that lets a user logged into Django access phpBB and MediaWiki

1. Without having to log in again and
2. Using the same username and password as on the Django site.

Some more specifications: being able to use Django's regular admin interface is a requirement, and being able to use Django's auth as usual would be a big plus.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You may want to share your experience in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/AuthManager so that such a job is made easier in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching Google for [*mediawiki django auth*](http://www.google.com/search?q=mediawiki+django+auth) brought up this [Django MediaWiki authentication extension](https://bitbucket.org/pythonian4000/django-mediawiki-authentication-by-user-id/).  That page also links to one about [Django login for phpBB](http://code.google.com/p/django-login-for-phpbb/).

Note that I haven't used or reviewed either of these plugins.  *Caveat utilitor.*